# Unable to setup PHPUnit in Intellij 10.5

Tags: php, symfony, intellij-idea, phpunit

I've got a Symfony2 project that I want to run unit tests for from IntelliJ 10.5 (I'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard).

I am able to run unit tests from the command line using the following:

```
> phpunit -c ./app
```

This runs fine, but I want to run the tests from within IntelliJ.

I've setup a Run/Debug Configuration > PHP Unit Tests, and selected XML File, and selected the app/phpunit.xml.dist file that comes with Symfony2.

When I run the unit tests in IntelliJ, I get the following error:

```
PHPUnit is missing from include paths.
Please adjust ''include_path'' variable in your ''php.ini'' configuration file.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've run php -i from the command line to locate the php.ini file, then added /usr/local/php5/lib/php/PHPUnit to that php.ini files include_paths setting.

However, despite doing this, I still get the same error. My php home is set to /usr/bin/php

Does anybody know what's up with this?

Comment: I can't believe I actually paid for this software, now I can't even freaking get it to run a stupid PHPUnit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that PHPUnit 3.6 is not supported in IDEA 10.5 PHP plug-in. Make sure that you are using compatible PHPUnit version.

Check that IDEA is configured to use the correct PHP interpreter that actually loads your modified php.ini file, there could be a case that PHP is using ini from different location or you are using another copy of PHP installed on the same system that is not configured for PHPUnit yet.

Also, if you have paid for software, you should use the [official support channel](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=IDEA) where we reply much faster than on third-party sites.

Comment: That's a bit disappointing, because I'm using PHPUnit 3.6.4. Honestly, I've paid for this software, and IntelliJ was advertised on the JetBrains site that it supports PHPUnit. Is there any chance of it getting it fixed? Would upgrading to IntelliJ 11 solve the issue?

Comment: What version of PHPUnit would you recommend I downgrade to?

Comment: Yes, PHPUnit 3.6 is supported in IDEA 11 (note that PHP plug-in is no longer bundled with this version and should be installed via Preferences | Plugins). The related issue that was addressed is http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-7554. PHPUnit 3.5 should work fine with IDEA 10.